# wordpress str_replace the content with tag

Tags: tags

it is possible to find tag in the content and replace with link?

```
function replace_content($content){
  foreach(get_the_tags() as $tag) {
    $out .= $tag->name .',';
    $csv_tags .= '"<a href="/' . $tag->slug . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>"';
  }
  $find  = array($out);
  $replace = array($csv_tags);
  $content = str_replace($find, $replace, $content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_content');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you are constructing an array with only **one** element, something like this:

```
array( 'green, yellow, red' )
```

instead of an array with multiple elements:

```
array( 'green', 'yellow', 'red' )
```

Try to replace these lines:

```
$out .= $tag->name .','; 
$csv_tags .= '"<a href="/' . $tag->slug . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>"';
```

with

```
$find[] = $tag->name;
$replace[] = '<a href="/' . $tag->slug . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
```

and remember to declare the arrays at the top:

```
$find = array();
$replace = array();
```